# Cant get my nav to float right. How do to get my nav to go to right?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

This is my Css code. I cant get my css to float the nav to the right. Any way on doing that? I attempted to use `float: right;` but that didn't work.
My HTML just has a header with a list holding my site navigation.

Here is my HTML if you need it as well:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Calistoga', cursive;
  background-color: #F5E9DF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* header */

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #F5E9DF;
  background-color: #1F2020;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* sitenavigation */

nav.sitenavigation {
  color: #F5E9DF;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.sitenavigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: #F5E9DF;
  margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F5E9DF;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:visited {
  color: #F5E9DF;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:hover,
nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
  color: #CC422B;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calistoga&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="100"></a>
  <h1 id="title">Rust Raiding Calculator</h1>
  <nav class="sitenavigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="raidcalculator.html">Raid Calculator</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us/Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: by *"cant get my css to float the nav to the right"* do you mean the `nav.sitenavigation`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left: auto` to the child item `.sitenavigation` to automatically push the element to the right. I prefer to avoid floats rules when approaching template decisions.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Calistoga', cursive;
  background-color: #F5E9DF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* header */

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #F5E9DF;
  background-color: #1F2020;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* sitenavigation */

nav.sitenavigation {
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #F5E9DF;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.sitenavigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: #F5E9DF;
  margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F5E9DF;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:visited {
  color: #F5E9DF;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:hover,
nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
  color: #CC422B;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calistoga&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="100"></a>
  <h1 id="title">Rust Raiding Calculator</h1>
  <nav class="sitenavigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="raidcalculator.html">Raid Calculator</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us/Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css Code for **nav.sitenavigation** class.

```
nav.sitenavigation {
  color: #F5E9DF;
  width: calc(100% - 31%);
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

[image: Here is a SS]

Answer (score 0):

```
nav.sitenavigation {
    color: #F5E9DF;
    text-align: right;
    width: 65%;
}
```

You can change width according to media query.